# Where is commitlogHeader in cassandra 0.8.1

Tags: cassandra

I've just updated to use cassandra version 0.8.1 to study..When i look at to the commitlog folder, there is no commitlogHeader file, where is it ? Is there any new update to manage commitlog in version 0.8.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

The header stored when CFs were flushed so log replay could skip replaying unnecessary mutations.

This information is now stored per-sstable instead.  (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2419)